# I can't compile a Visual Studio Solution with Blazor Client/Server/Shared projects and Xamarin App/App.iOS/App.Android projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, blazor, visual-studio-mac, .net-7.0

I would like to create a Visual Studio slution with 6 projects:

- Blazor.Client
- Blazor.Server
- Blazor.Shared
- XamarinApp
- XamarinApp.Android
- XamarinApp.iOS

The first I did was create two individual solutions with the Visual Studio Wizard, the first one with the Blazor template and the second one with the Xamarin template.

I close the Xamarin solution and then I try to add the projects of the Xamarin solution one by one.
The first one was the XamarinApp and I try to compile and works fine.
The second one was the XamarinApp.iOS and when I try to compile fails. It happends the same remove this project and adding the XamarinApp.Android.

First I susspected that the problem is the Debug|iPhoneSimulator and Debug|iPhone, but when it fails also with the XamarinApp.Android project that it not contains the Debug|iPhone and Debug|iPhoneSimulator I was lost.

The error I obtain when I try to compile is (translated the text from spanish to english to do more clear it):

> Target ResolvePackageAssets:
> /Users/myuser/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/17.0/MSBuild/1140_3/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5):
> error NETSDK1005: The resource file
> "/Users/myuser/Projects/MySolution/Blazor.Shared/obj/project.assets.json"
> does not have a target for ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0". be sure that
> that the restore was executed and that it included "net70"
> in TargetFrameworks for your project. Finished compilation of
> target "ResolvePackageAssets" in project "Blazor.Shared.csproj"
> -- ERROR.
>
> Build of project "Blazor.Shared.csproj" finished -- ERROR.

If I remove the XamarinApp.Andriod and XamarinApp.iOS from solution, all projects compile again.

Any idea?

EDIT:
I discovered that when I add the XamarinApp.Android and XamarinApp.iOS, the "Build with MSBuild on Mono" option pass to be checked. If I uncheck this option all projects but XamarinApp.Android and XamarinApp.iOS compiles, and for this projects the error is the next one:

> ERROR al compilar.
>
> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
> '/Users/acayon/Projects/MySolution/XamarinApp/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/ref/XamarinApp.dll'
> could not be found
> 0 Advertencia(s)
> 1 Errores

Comment: It looks like that you want to integrate Xamarin projects with Blazor projects and fail to compile the solution. It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)

Comment: Yes I would like to create a Xamarin App and connect with JSON Controllers of a Blazor Server project.
If you think it looks like bug I will report it to de developer community as you suggest me. I hope I'm not doing something wrong instead of being a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: I created it:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/I-cant-compile-a-Visual-Studio-Solution/10373278

Comment: I just discover that the problem seams to be related witn the "Build with MSBuild on Mono" check. If it is checked, the solution give the error I explain in the first post. If it is not checked, the common Xamarin project compiles but Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS fails due a problems of reference to the common Xamarin project.

Comment: So you may need uncheck `Build with MSBuild on mono`. And you can add the error message to your post after unchecking `Build with MSBuild on mono`.

Comment: Would need to see the error you are getting after unchecking Build with MSBuild on Mono. My guess is it is a 'CS0006 Metadata file could not be found' error. There is a workaround to set ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir  to true in the .NET Standard project. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-and-Restore-Errors-when-a-solution/10278382

Comment: I updated the first post to add the new error I recived when Visual Studio tryes to compile with the option "Build with MSBuild on mono" disabled.
Please @MattWard, could you confirm if your guess are in the correct way? And also, could you explain me what is the ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir parameter and how it works? I don't know where is and how to change it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that CS0006 looks like a known issue with a classic Xamarin project referencing a .NET Standard SDK style project. You would need to update the .NET Standard's property group with ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir set to true and possibly also add ProduceReferenceAssembly set to true. `<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Wooo, it seams magic. I added the line <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir> and it compiles perfectly. Thank you. Would you add a answer to the first post in order I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log below:

> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
> '/Users/acayon/Projects/MySolution/XamarinApp/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/ref/XamarinApp.dll'
> could not be found 0 Advertencia(s) 1 Errores

You need to update the .NET Standard's property group with `ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir` set to true in your csproj file as Matt suggested like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>     
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>   
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is because if an external system requires the reference assembly in `OutDir`, you need to set the MSBuild property `ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir` to `true` in your project file.